# Any easy way in C# to get the filepath+filename of itself?

Tags: c#, .net

Hey guys, I'm coding a C# program to "Install" itself on the PC and run at starup to manage some scheduled tasks I have. I already have most  of it done, including prompting the user, adding to startup, and such. But I want to copy the EXE when they run it after download, to C:\Program Files\Company\Program.exe

Is there any easy way to get the filepath+exe of a C# program from within the program? I've tried some System.Environment methods, and GetModuleInfo(), but I think I may just be overlooking something.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: That requires administator privileges on many systems. Many users no longer run as admin by default. Are you sure this is a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

Answer (score 0):

// Get and display the full name of the EXE assembly.
string exeAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().FullName;
Console.WriteLine(exeAssembly);